# Python queue using 95% CPU

Tags: python, queue

I've noticed that the queue in my program, which is running in it's own thread, uses up more than 95% of my Raspberry Pi Zero's CPU. Are there ways to reduce this CPU usage?

I have tried using the `block` and `timeout` arguments, but neither has an effect.

```
while True:
    try:
        item = q.get()
    except queue.Empty:
        time.sleep(1)
        continue
```

Comment: is strange because by default the get on a *queue* is blocking without timeout, do you have other `except`cases ? is your *queue* valid ? do you enter in the `except queue.Empty` ? What is your version of Python ? Are you sure the CPU is get that by code ?

Comment: As bruno says, this isn't an issue with your `time.sleep()` call. Can you provide more code?

Comment: `Queue.get(false)` can raises the *Empty* exception, but your code cannot, so except if your queue contains a looooooooooooooooot of elements or an element is continuously added in, that code cannot get so much CPU, it is elsewhere. Or *q* is not a queue and you have an additional `except: pass`

Comment: Sure enough, there I had another `While` loop following the one above that needed some `time.sleep(1)` code to reduce CPU usage. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try to do not use queue.Empty